# How can I expose my material-ui theme to the console like material-ui site?

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui

I am working on a React project and have decided to use material-ui for the styling, but am also having to learn how to use it in the process. I keep running into bumps with the theme-ing, have been reading the material-ui documentation and other resources online, but am still having trouble getting a grasp on it. I thought being able to see my theme in the Chrome inspector/dev tools would be helpful as material-ui has done on their site, but I don't know how to do it. How can I expose my theme to the console?

[material-ui exposes a global theme variable on all the pages](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to have created a custom theme, your theme object should be exactly the same as on the website!

If you really want to see yours in the console try to console log it when declaring your styles on a component like this!

```
const styles = theme => console.log(theme) || ({
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
});
```

And then when exporting your component use

```
withStyles(styles)(YourComponentHere);
```

Comment: *Yay!* Thank you! I was confused as to where to put this and wasn't sure it would work with `MuiThemeProvider` and my `react-router`, but it did! I just wrapped it around my entire App component.


 ```imports

const styles = theme => console.log(theme)
const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Routes />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
)

export default withStyles(styles)(App)```

Comment: I recommend using it selectively. It's calles JSS or CSSinJS. It helps you styling components separately where necessary. Good luck on your MaterialUI journey!

Comment: Thank you, @Nielsvandenbroeck ! If you don't mind, what do you mean by _selectively_? The console logging or the theme-ing? I'm somewhat aware of the heavy rendering load if I have custom styling included in every component file, which is why I thought I would be better off to do as much as I could in the theme.

Comment: I meant that you could just wrap the components you want to have custom styling on selectively and not just have 1 big style dump in your app since it becomes unmaintainable quite quickly imo. But that's just my opinion ofcourse!

Comment: **Update**
I actually had used `createMuiTheme()` to create my own theme and could not view it with your solution. The arrow function you provided above shows me material-ui's default `theme`. I wanted to see my theme, in which case, I needed to do this instead of the arrow function: `const styles = theme; console.log(theme)` which showed me my theme. The rest was fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest stashing `theme` on `window` once in your `<App />` component:

```
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.theme = theme;
    console.info({ theme });
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* ... */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```